# docker-compose nginx/certbot website does not load

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I'm setting up a very simple docker compose script. It should setup nginx, create some let's Encrypt certificate and then serve the nginx default website to the browser in a secured website.

However, when I go to the website it loads for a long time and then doesn't give me any useful error message, other then yourfootprint.dk took too long to respond.

It works to create Certificates. So I know that the certbot part works.
I also know that the server and the domain works. If I run a simple nginx container without the docker-compose and the nginx.dev.conf the nginx default website is served fine.

I have a hunch that my nginx.dev.conf file is wrong and incoming requests will run in an infinite loop.

./docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:stable
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/nginx.dev.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/:ro
      - ./data/certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw
      - ./data/certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw
```

./data/nginx/nginx.dev.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name yourfootprint.dk www.yourfootprint.dk;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://yourfootprint.dk$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name yourfootprint.dk;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/yourfootprint.dk/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/yourfootprint.dk/privkey.pem;
    
    location / {
        # ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the certificate in /data/certbot/conf then the solution is easy:

./docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  app:
    {{your_configurations_here}}
  {{other_services...}}:
    {{other_services_configuraitons}}
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DOMAIN
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /data/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates:ro
      - /data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/
      - /data/certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/
  certbot:
    container_name: certbot
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    command: >-
             certonly --reinstall --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/certbot
             --email ${EMAIL} --agree-tos --no-eff-email
             -d ${DOMAIN} 
    volumes:
      - /data/certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/
      - /data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/
```

/data/nginx/templates/default.template.conf
server {
listen [::]:80;
listen 80;
server_name $DOMAIN; #$DOMAIN must be defined in the environment
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

./etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name $DOMAIN; 

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/privkey.pem;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }
    
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_pass http://app:80;
  }
}
```

If not, then I think you need to split the process into two phases: an initiation phase and a production phase. I describe that in details [here](https://blog.jarrousse.org/an-elegant-way-to-use-docker-compose-to-obtain-and-renew-a-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-with-certbot-and-configure-the-nginx-service-to-use-it/). The idea is to have a docker-compose file to initiate the letsencrypt certificate, and another docker-compose file to run the system and renew the certificate.

So without further ado, here is the file structure and content that is working really well for me (you still need to adapt the files locations and content to suit your needs):

- ./setup.sh
- ./docker-compose-initiate.yaml
- ./docker-compose.yaml
- ./etc/nginx/templpates/default.conf.template
- ./etc/nginx/templpates-initiation/default.conf.template

## The setup in 2 phases:

In the first phase "the initiation phase" we will run an nginx container, and a certbot container just to obtain the ssl certificate for the first time and store it on the host ./etc/letsencrypt folder

I the second phase "the operation phase" we run all necessary services for the app including nginx that will use the letsencrypt folder this time to serve https on port 443, a certbot container will also run (on demand) to renew the certificate. We can add a cron job for that. So the setup.sh script is a simple convenience script that runs the commands one after another:

```
#!/bin/bash
# the script expects two arguments:
# - the domain name for which we are obtaining the ssl certificatee
# - the Email address associated with the ssl certificate
echo DOMAIN=$1 >> .env
echo EMAIL=$2 >> .env

# Phase 1 "Initiation"
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose-first.yaml up -d nginx
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose-first.yaml up certbot
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose-first.yaml down

# Phase 2 "Operation"    
crontab ./etc/crontab
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

## Phase 1: The ssl certificate initiation phase:

./docker-compose-initiate.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    environment:
      - DOMAIN
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./etc/nginx/templates-initiate:/etc/nginx/templates:ro
      - ./etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
      - ./certbot/data:/var/www/certbot
  certbot:
    container_name: certbot
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    command: >- 
             certonly --reinstall --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/certbot
             --email ${EMAIL} --agree-tos --no-eff-email
             -d ${DOMAIN}
    volumes:
      - ./etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/data:/var/www/certbot
```

- ./etc/nginx/templates-initiate/default.conf.template

  server {
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;
  server_name $DOMAIN;
  location ~/.well-known/acme-challenge {
  allow all;
  root /var/www/certbot;
  }
  }

## Phase 2: The operation phase

./docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  app:
    {{your_configurations_here}}
  {{other_services...}}:
    {{other_services_configuraitons}}
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DOMAIN
    depends_on:
      - matomo
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./etc/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates:ro
      - ./etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/data:/var/www/certbot
      - /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
  certbot:
    container_name: certbot
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    command: >-
             certonly --reinstall --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/certbot
             --email ${EMAIL} --agree-tos --no-eff-email
             -d ${DOMAIN} 
    volumes:
      - ./etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/data:/var/www/certbot
```

server {
listen [::]:80;
listen 80;

```
server_name $DOMAIN;

return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

}

./etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name $DOMAIN; 

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/privkey.pem;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_pass http://app:80;
  }
}
```